# How to show Login component first Instead of app-component Angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

My app-component

```
 <mat-drawer-container>
<mat-drawer mode="side" [opened]="sideBarOpen">
<app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
</mat-drawer>
<mat-drawer-content>
  <app-header (toggleSidebarForMe)="sideBarToggler()"></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-drawer-content>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
```

I want to show login page without the sidebar and navbar component. When user hits the URL login page will show with navbar and sidebar. After successful login Dashboard page should be shown. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the sidebar on the login page, use a structural directive (*ngIf) and check if the route is login